# FINDSTR RegEx assistance?

Tags: regex, findstr

I'm processing the output from an SVNLOOK command. All the lines returned start with A, U or D. I need to find all the rows that do NOT start with "D". What's the Regex pattern for this? I tried ^[^D] (starting with, not "D") but that doesn't work. If you want to test the following test data

FILEA.txt:
A file1.txt
U file2.txt
D file3.txt

The output of "FINDSTR pattern FILEA.txt" needs to be only the lines that DON'T start with "D", so the A and the U.

ANy help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you wrap the pattern in quotes:

```
findstr "^[^D]" filea.txt
```

Another option is to use `-v` to reverse the match:

```
findstr -v "^D" filea.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail. The Regex was for a FINDSTR in a BAT file. I originally was using "^[^D]" but just realized that I need to "escape" the carats. I changed it to "^^[^^D]" and now it works.